# Static Text box display every page in Multiple columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I want to display a blank text box at every page display in crystal report with Multiple Column as in the picture below. Can we do that in Crystal Report 2016 SP7?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports lays out content in sections.
So you need to identify the section you wish to use for the text object.
Then, simply place the text object in that section.

If the problem is that you don't know which section, please describe the use case in more detail.